# Fail to remove duplicate SPN

Tags: active-directory, spn

I am seeing event id 4 on computers on my Windows domain, and according to MicroSoft. I have a duplicate, which appears to be confirmed by:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> setspn -X
Checking domain DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM
Processing entry 0
{14E52635-0A95-4a5c-BDB1-E0D0C703B6C8}/FPS1 is registered on these accounts:
        CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM
        CN=Backup Service,CN=Users,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM

{14E52635-0A95-4a5c-BDB1-E0D0C703B6C8}/FPS1.MYDOMAIN.COM is registered on these accounts:
        CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM
        CN=Backup Service,CN=Users,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM

found 2 groups of duplicate SPNs.
```

As per MicroSoft's instructions I have identified the computer names with "setspn -Q" and then tried to delete the duplicate SPN as follows:

```
setspn -D "{14E52635-0A95-4a5c-BDB1-E0D0C703B6C8}/FPS1" fps
setspn -D "{14E52635-0A95-4a5c-BDB1-E0D0C703B6C8}/FPS1" fps1
```

where those are two computer names found (yet they were decommissioned long ago). How do I get setspn -X to stop reporting the duplicate?  And why does the report refer to users "administrator" and "backup service"?  And why is it referring to hosts long ago deleted?

I have to clean something up here...but can't figure out how

(domain name obfuscated)

Comment: No. `setspn -d "spn" hostname` would work if your spns are on computer objects. They are not. They are on user objects. SPNs are usually associated with computers. In this case you can either substitute the user samaccountname, or use AD Users and Computers, enable Advanced View, and delete the offending duplicate SPN from the Attribute Editor tab of the user account. Presumably the Administrator account.

Comment: I agree with the above comment about using Attribute Editor to remove the "servicePrincipalName" entries from the user accounts. But I also wish it was an actual answer that could be accepted and the question then closed.